# Java, Constructor w/ array as an argument & user input from Driver

Tags: java, arrays, parameters, constructor

I'm pretty new to java and I seem to get held up on small things, especially when it comes to methods with parameters.

This is for a class assignment, mainly about exception handling which I believe I got correct.  I know what's going wrong I just don't know how to fix it.

Let me explain.  Assignment asks us to set up a constructor that takes a double array as an argument (for test scores) & throw an IllegalArgumentException if a score is outside of the range 0-100.  The program is calculating the average of the test scores correctly, but my issue is (I think) nothing is actually being passed into the constructor so that the constructor can look for an exception.  I believe it's just running through the constructor but not passing anything into it that is why the exception is not getting thrown when I pass in a negative number.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, any help is greatly appreciated!

```
/**Write a class named TestScores. The class constructor should 
 * accept an array of test scores as its argument. The class should 
 * have a method that returns the average of the test scores. If any
 * test score in the array is negative or greater than 100, the class
 * should throw an IllegalArgumentException. Demonstrate the class in a program.
*/

public class TestScores {

   private double testScores[];
   ScoresDemo TD = new ScoresDemo();

    public TestScores(double scores[]) {
        testScores = scores;
        try {
            for(int i = 0; i < testScores.length; i++) {
                if(scores[i] < 0 || scores[i] > 100) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Test scores must be between 0 and 100");
                }
                else {
                    testScores[i] = scores[i];
                }
            }
        }catch(IllegalFormatException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
   }

    public double averageScores() {
        double average = 0;
        int count = testScores.length;
        int sum = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < testScores.length; i++) {
                sum += testScores[i];
            }
         average = sum / count;
         return average;
    } 
}
```

"DRIVER" CLASS

```
public class ScoresDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double testScores[] = new double [5];
        TestScores scores = new TestScores(testScores);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int i = 0; i < testScores.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter some test scores: ");
            testScores[i] = scan.nextDouble();
        }
        System.out.println("The average of the test scores is " + scores.averageScores());
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you construct your object before giving values to `testScores`. Since the elements in `testScores` (in the main) will be assigned by default to the value 0d (their default value), the exception is not thrown inside the constructor.

Comment: Oh so I should set up the constructor object after the for loop?

Comment: @sjud9227 - Populate the array, *then* pass it to the TestScores constructor. So, yes. Call the for-loop first to set up the scores array, and then create your TestScores object.

Comment: Ok cool.  Other than that am I doing everything else correctly?  Someone posted something about the exception not being correct, but I don't see it anymore so it may have been deleted

Comment: One last question if you guys do not mind.  I create a testScores[] array in Driver and in my TestScores class.  Is that the correct way to do so?  It seems redundant, and is it good in this case to name them both testScores[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your constructor does not re-evaluate when you populate the array. It is evaluated once, when it is called. Unfortunately, you're calling it when you first create the array, at which point all the scores are the default value (0d).

What you instead need to do is first populate the array, then pass it to the `TestScores` constructor. That is, swap out the order of the for-loop and the constructor:

```
public class ScoresDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double testScores[] = new double [5];
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int i = 0; i < testScores.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter some test scores: ");
            testScores[i] = scan.nextDouble();
        }
        // Now that we have a populated testScores array, call the constructor:
        TestScores scores = new TestScores(testScores);
        System.out.println("The average of the test scores is " + scores.averageScores());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for such the fast responses and detailed answers!!  I hate when people answer correctly at the same time lol.  I'm just gonna go by timing and answer Roddy's.

Answer (score 1):

You pass `testScores` only when it is a still a empty array. You need to pass it later or update it (pass it again).

Answer (score 1):

No exception is going to be thrown since there's no value in the array that's "invalid"; that is, since each value in the array is assigned its default value of `0.0`, there's no way that the exception will be thrown.

The issue remains, however, that you're passing in an array with zeroes and expecting a lot of math to happen on it, which isn't the case.  You need to pass in an initialized array with actual values in it before you see results.

It's just a matter of instantiating an instance of `TestScores` *after* you fill the array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        double testScores[] = new double [5];
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int i = 0; i < testScores.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter some test scores: ");
            testScores[i] = scan.nextDouble();
        }
        TestScores scores = new TestScores(testScores);
        System.out.println("The average of the test scores is " + scores.averageScores());
    }
```